# Apache Beam Dataflow pipeline build and deploy with Bazel

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, bazel

Looking at the official [Python Beam documentation page](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/) it seems like the only way to do deployments is to have a `setup.py` that defines dependencies that exist within your repo or externally.

But this doesn't quite work with the Bazel way of managing Python dependencies (i.e. I have no setup.py file) or separate `requirements.txt` file for each pipeline in my repo.

How does one package and deploy jobs to runners using Bazel?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script that runs `pip freeze > ...` to generate the requirements files for your pipelines, then use them to deploy your pipelines.

If multiple pipelines share the same set of Python dependencies and the super set of all their dependencies is not that big, you can build a custom container to submit with all the jobs.